# initialize vector in class

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

I have the following problem. I have a class, say

```
class MyClass{
public:
  class MyNumber;
  MyClass(char const *filename);
  class MyNumber{
  public:
    MyNumber(int n) : n(n) {}
  private:
    int n;
  };

private:
  std::vector<MyNumber> mynumbers
};
```

Now I want to write a constructor for the class MyClass, which reads a file and depending on the content of the file initializes the vector mynumbers. What I did is the following

```
MyClass::Myclass (char const * filename){
  int num = 0;
  std::string line;
  std::getline(file, line);              
  std::stringstream ss(line);              
  ss >> num; 
  mynumbers(num,MyNumber(5));

}
```

But I get the error "type 'std::vector' does not provide a call operator". I also can't use a constructor initializer lists (at least I think so) since it depends on my input file how big my vector has to be.
Can somebody tell me how this is done?

Comment: A constructor that does any I/O (beyond logging) is usually a bad idea. Consider moving the reading of the file to a separate setup function.

Comment: I recommend not reading files in a constructor.  Create a "load" or "initialize" method instead.  What happens if reading the file fails or a copy of the object needs to be created (such as `std::vector` does).

Comment: `mynumbers.resize(num, MyNumber(5));` ?

Comment: I suggest against using nested classes, as they add complexity to the program (which makes the debugging and testing more complex as well).

Comment: @Thomas Matthews. I am throwing an error if the file format is not as i expect it to be. I don't see what advantage I have when I write a method instead of a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the method `assign`

```
mynumbers.assign(num,MyNumber(5));
```

As for this statement

```
mynumbers(num,MyNumber(5));
```

then it corresponds to a call of a function operator. However the standard class `std::vector` does not has such an operator. The object `mynumbers` in the constructor was already created/ So you can only assign it with new values. You can not call its constructor a second time. On the other hand the method `assign` is overloaded such away that it corresponds to the most of constructors of the class.

Comment: thanks this works. Can you explain in a short sentence why this works but the one in my question doesn't?